# How can I test locally that my Aragon OSx plugin is working?

Tags: solidity, testing, dao, repositories

I'm creating a plugin and want to test it locally.

While reviewing examples at https://github.com/aragon/osx/blob/develop/packages/contracts/test/plugins, I found two different ways to deploy a local DAO to install and test the plugin.

- One approach uses a `DaoMock` contract, as shown in this example: https://github.com/aragon/osx/blob/a362749d3859edcfbb301cf5fb8ed81b1b510337/packages/contracts/test/plugins/counter-example/counter-plugin-setup.ts#L7.
- The other approach involves using a function to deploy a new DAO, as demonstrated here: https://github.com/aragon/osx/blob/a362749d3859edcfbb301cf5fb8ed81b1b510337/packages/contracts/test/plugins/governance/admin/admin.ts#L69.

Which approach would be best?
In both cases, I think it means copying some code from the [OSx repository](https://github.com/aragon/osx) to my local plugin repository.

I checked whether any of these functions are exported in the OSx npm package, but it seems they are not.

Do you have any recommendations? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Check if plugin was published successfully

First, you'll want to revise that your plugin is in fact published into the protocol. You can do this by going into the Subgraph ([mainnet](https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/aragon/osx-mainnet/playground), [goerli](https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/aragon/osx-goerli/playground)) and calling:

```
query GetPlugins {
  pluginRepos {
      subdomain
    }
}
```

That will return a list of all plugins published into the protocol. There, you should be able to check whether yours was successfully published.

### Check if the plugin is installed successfully

My recommendation would be to create a real DAO and test it using a flow similar to the you can see with the [Admin plugin](https://github.com/aragon/osx/tree/develop/packages/contracts/src/plugins/governance/admin).

You will need to write a `PluginSetup` contract containing your `installation` script and then the plugin itself. (Remember: a plugin is always composed of a `Plugin` contract, containing all plugin logic + a `PluginSetup` contract, containing installation/uninstallation/upgrade requirements).

You shouldn't need to copy code, you can import the base classes or interfaces directly from `@aragon/osx/...` if you install the [OSx NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aragon/osx).

Also, there are two ways to install a plugin:

1. On DAO creation, you pass an array with the encoded params of the plugins that you want to use. Here's an example of this using the SDK: https://devs.aragon.org/docs/sdk/examples/tokenVoting-client/installation
2. When a DAO is already created, you call `MyPluginSetup.prepareInstallation(...)`. Then, you use an existing governance plugin to create a proposal with an `action` that does `PluginSetupProcessor.applyInstallation(...)` to grant all the needed permissions.
   Here's an example of how to pass encoded actions for proposals using the SDK: https://devs.aragon.org/docs/sdk/examples/tokenVoting-client/create-proposal-with-actions